# How to avoid CHKJ3010W: Welcome Files cannot begin or end with a /

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets

My welcome file list looks like below:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This raises below warning in Eclipse:

```
CHKJ3010W: Welcome Files cannot begin or end with a /.  in web.xml
```

If we remove the / in front of WEB-INF, the page is not properly served in JBoss. If we add the / we are getting above mentioned warning.

How to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify file that is publicly accessible. Look http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.WelcomeFileList

Create public `index.jsp` which will include data from your `/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`